# SpecFlow steps class async initialization

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time and I haven't found anything solid yet.
We have a lot of step classes in our project and, some of them, use a base class to "initialize" the class, using a base constructor.
However, this is bad, because we are putting way too much logic into a constructor and it is not async/await "friendly".

Is there any construct in SpecFlow that will help initialize a steps class just before it is used? Likst a hook of some sorts that will run on step class initialization?

Thank you in advance for any help :-)

Comment: Your constructors shouldn't be doing anything exciting at all, async or no. Wait until the step is actually tasked to perform something (`Then`). Before that, use the `Given` and `When` only to record what's going to happen at the `Then`, and the constructors only to set up whatever containers are necessary to gather this info, which should take little to no time at all. Use protected methods for shared functionality. I've had some success with this for tests that access databases -- you really don't want to do this in the constructor, or even the preconditions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree on the constructor part, that's why I'm refactoring it. Using an extra step, is the obvious answer. However, "Given that I am lazy" (pun intended), I was hoping to find a way to do that part automatically :-D

Comment: There are [hooks](https://specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/), but they're intended to be used to do things for all steps/tests at once. They won't allow you to customize the logic based on the step type. They *might* be usable, depending on the kind of logic you've got in your base classes and how general it is. Otherwise, though, TANSTAAFL -- it pays off to sit down and get your test code in tip top shape before you tackle the rest of the code; it's something that really pays off cumulative dividends.